# Handle Server Side Laravel Validation with Angular2

Tags: laravel, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have started using Angular2 recently with laravel API's. but I don't know how to handle server side validation with Angular2.

I'm returning this response from server side.

```
`{"success":false,
"code":422,
"error":[],
"message":
{
"name":["The name field is required."],
"email":["The email field is required."]
}
}`
```

Can anyone please help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get instance ofform in `@Component`, then set `.errors` object. Something like:

```
save(data: any){
    this.http.post(data).subscribe((response) => this.handleSuccess(response),
    (errorResponse) => {
        if(errorResponse.status !== 422){
            this.handleHttpError(errorResponse);
        }else{
            let data = errorResponse.json();
            Object.keys(data).forEach((fieldName) => {
                this.form.controls[fieldName].setErrors({backend: data[fieldName]});
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this.form.controls[fieldName].setErrors({backend: data[fieldName]});
from where I can get form in above line;